# web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_A_AMOUNT

Tags: python, ethereum, router, solidity, remix

Please, help. I want to add liquidity to token pair: weth/uni-v2. I calculate optimal numbers of tokens to add. After approving to router withdraw tokens I execute "addLiquidityETH" function. In Remix IDE this function execute without mistakes, but in my python dapp I receive this error:

*web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_A_AMOUNT.*

[getAmountsOut call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A2b9.png)

How can I solve this problem? I calculate optimal numbers of tokens with "getAmountsOut" function

Comment: Do you have enough eth/bnb native token on the address?